# Auto-match criteria by location

Tags: google-play-games

How does Google match two players looking for a random game?
For our app it is better to match people from the same location.
Is Google already preferring people living closer together when matching them?

If not: Is there a better approach to match players than seperating the world by longitudes and latitudes, generating a unique id per square and use setVariant(id)?

Comment: Perhaps you could try asking this question in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

When players initiate a multiplayer game, they can choose to invite specific people or have Google Play games services automatically select other participants randomly via auto-matching. They can also request a mix of the two (for example, one specific player from their circles, and two auto-matched players).

If players choose to invite a specific person to a game, depending on their account settings, the UI they use, and the game’s scopes, they may have different people available to choose from.

- In general, inviters will always be able to invite recent opponents, and will always be able to automatch players.
- In the Google-supplied default UI, they will also see the “Nearby players” option.
- In the Google-supplied default UI, players with discoverable profiles will see circled friends as well, independent of whether they have the PLUS_LOGIN scope.
- Using the getInvititablePlayers() method, games that have requested the PLUS_LOGIN scope will get circled friends in the return values, independent of whether they have a discoverable profile.

An auto-match participant does not have to be a contact in the local player's circles or any other connection. When auto-matching, Google Play games services simply looks for other participants at that time who are also initiating a game and requesting to be auto-matched. Auto-match participants do not receive notifications to join a game; from their perspective, it appears as though they are individually initiating the game.

For more information, you can check the [Real-time Multiplayer](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer#participants).

When using [Turn-based Multiplayer](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer#turn-based_match_basics), the participants in a match can fall into one of these categories:

- Initiating player
- Auto-matched players
- Invited players

Comment: The app is turnbased if that's relevant. And almost finished, so the general procerede is known.
Im sorry but that does not answer my question. Inviting friends works fine. Using the "Nearby players" is pretty much useless, because it uses only bluetooth (and wifi?). So it's only working when those two people are standing next to each other.

We want to match two people based on their location. Does the automatch option already do this? Or is there a better approch than stated in my question above?

Comment: when you use auto match, you can't determine or make sure that the other participant is on your same location. Because automatch select the opponent/participant who are initiating a game at that time. My answer is came from the Google document, so I think that is all the way of matching a game with others.